# Passing a member name as argument

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass a member of class as argument to a function (not member method). The simple example of my intention would be like this.

```
template <typename ObjType>
void myOutput(ObjType* obj, ????)
{
    std::cout << obj->???? << std::endl;
}

struct A
{
    int a;
};

struct B
{
    std::string b;
};

int main()
{
    A A1;
    B B1;
    A1.a = 1;
    B1.b = "something";

    myOutput(&A1, A1::a);
    myOutput(&B1, B1::b);

    return 0;
}
```

So my question is what should i replace "????" with? I am not using C++11.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

To clarify my intentions. The function myOutput doesn't really know the name of my member, and i do not want to use a function like memberToString() or something.

So the output should look like this for first call.

```
void myOutput(A* obj, ????)
{
    std::cout << obj->a << std::endl;
}
```

and for the second

```
void myOutput(B* obj, ????)
{
    std::cout << obj->b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If you are passing the object, why would you want to pass a member variable as well? You can directly access them using the object provided they are public.

Comment: why you're passing two arguments ? what exactly you want to do ? you can't call an independent method directly from main() until it is static.Please check

Comment: Why don't you just add one more parameter to your func like template <typename ObjType,typename memeber>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the member name at compile time, you can use a member pointer to refer to the member.

```
template <typename ObjType, typename MembType>
void myOutput(ObjType* obj, MembType memb)
{
    std::cout << obj->*memb << std::endl;
}
```

This can then be called as such:

```
myOutput(&A1, &A::a);
myOutput(&B1, &B::b);
```

Naturally, you should ask yourself why it is you want to do this, and if it wouldn't be possible to simply pass `A1->a` or `B1->b` directly into the function as a single argument, instead.

Comment: Should be `&A::a` and &B::b`.